# Python Error On Coding Judge NZEC

Tags: python-2.7, runtime-error

I have the following program. I can't figure out why it is giving NZEC error on spoj judge.
Please Help.

```python
import math
def main()
    n = int(raw_input())
    while n != 0:
        a = (n * n) / (math.pi * 2)
        print "{0:.2f}".format(a)
        n = int(raw_input())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: def main(): colon is there in the original code!